# Georeferencing Old German Map in ArcMap that uses Ferro Meridian and very uncommon projection

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, georeferencing, germany

I am trying to georeference an old map of the German Reich from 1930's. The map is based on the topographische Übersichtskarte des Deutschen Reiches 1:200000.

The coordinates depicted on the map, that I want to use to georeference it, use the Ferro Meridian. I know that the original map uses a **conic projection** (German: Schnittkegelprojektion) with **two parallels at 50° and 53°**. Axis of the cone is the same as the axis of the earth. I don't know anything about the central meridian other than that the angle between the central meridian and the corner/border meridians (German: Randmeridiane, do not exactly know the translation) is 0°23'28''5.

**The issue is to find a suitable projection, which fits ok and at the same time allows me to input the coordinates in Ferro using ArcMap as the geoereferencing tool.**

[image: Part of the map]

Comment: Do you have projected coordinates or lat-lon values only? If you have projected coordinates, I would georeference the map to those coordinates (leave coordinate system unknown) then use techniques similar to [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/identifying-an-unknown-coordinate-system.htm) except define a custom PCS using a ferro-based GCS.

Comment: Also see [Cliff Mugnier's article on Germany](https://www.asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2015journals/PERS_June_2015/HTML/files/assets/basic-html/index.html#437).

Comment: I uploaded part of the map as I do not really know what you mean by projected coordinates. As you can see I have the lat-lon values. I know in terms of degree, the width and length of grid.

Comment: The central meridian (ferro-meridian) was changed to Greenwich in 1923 and then was determinate to 17°40' west. On your map, you can find both values i think. So 12° east (Greenwich) corresponds to 30° east (ferro). On your map it looks like the central meridian of the projection is near 32° east (ferro).

Comment: some similar overview map https://www.landkartenshop.de/product_info.php?products_id=11479, both systems are printet on the map border.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes it has both on it, but the Ferro latitude values are much clearer attributable to certain grid lines and thus inputting these directly is much less error prone. How did you determine/guess the central meridian?

Comment: The central meridian on a conic projection is a straight vertical line, like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Conic. It's a guess of course, but you could try that and see how it fits.

Comment: Because you have only geographic coordinates, you'll need a clever way to process the control points for georeferencing. ferro into greenwich into conic?

Comment: I am not sure. The end goal is to extract the lat-lon values of the data points depicted on the map.

Answer (score 4):

See the [first two maps](http://polski.mapywig.org/viewpage.php?page_id=42). They have both Ferro and Greenwich longitudes directly labeled, so you can determine Greenwich-based control points. I would try 3-5 points left right at both top, middle, and bottom of the map and try directly georeferencing to lat/lon. Note that the longitude lines bifurcate so you'll have to pick the main line.

If that doesn't work well enough, try building a Lambert conformal conic projected coordinate system (PCS) using central meridian = 32° Ferro AKA 14°20' Greenwich and standard parallels about 50° and 53°. Use the Create Fishnet tool to make a 1°x1° graticule and project it to the Lambert PCS. Use that to georeference the map. The original map's graticule is 2' so you might be able to discern 1/3' or 1/4'.

For the datum, about the best you can do is DHDN. It's at least on the same ellipsoid (Bessel 1841).

Comment: I tried your second version. However, I have trouble to get the Fishnet into the right position. Is there anyway that I can input the lat/lon values as the X and Y coordinates?